# PLSQL Trigger get fired through SQL loader

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Is the table gets triggered while we do insert through SQL loader? 
PLease explain in details

Answer (score 3):

Oracle will execute `INSERT` triggers if conventional load is used, but [not when you use direct load](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_modes.htm#i1008078) (with the option `DIRECT=true`):

> With the conventional path load method, arrays of rows are inserted with standard SQL INSERT statements—integrity constraints and insert triggers are automatically applied. But **when you load data with the direct path, SQL*Loader disables some integrity constraints and all database triggers**.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a conventional load or an external table load, triggers will fire and any active constraints are checked.

If you do a direct path load, both triggers and constraint checks are bypassed.

You can read more in the [SQL Loader documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm) (link leads to Oracle 10g docs).